# Static IP isn't accessible outside of the home network

Tags: wireless-router, port-forwarding, static-ip, iis-8

I have Windows 2012 server with HTTP server enabled through the firewall. I mapped my static IP  to  my local IIS using the router's port forwarding. Everything worked fine for awhile.

All of a sudden I found that my static IP only gets resolved in my home network (I'm using noip.com DUC to emulate it, but it's pretty stable). Haven't seen it changing in last 6 months) even though it used to work fine in any network a few weeks back.

How do I fix it and what is the problem?

---

Update:

**tracert**

```
 1     1 ms     2 ms     1 ms  [Kind_of_My_IP].ntlworld.ie [My_Public_IP]
```

**pathping**

```
Tracing route to [Kind_of_My_IP].ntlworld.ie [My_IP]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  0  My_PC_Name [192.168.0.**]
  1  [Kind_of_My_IP].ntlworld.ie [My_IP]

Computing statistics for 25 seconds...
            Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address
  0                                           My_PC_Name [My_IP]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  1    3ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  [Kind_of_My_IP].ntlworld.ie [My_IP]

Trace complete.
```

**pathping to Google**

```
Tracing route to google.com [74.125.24.100]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     4 ms  192.168.*.*
  2    11 ms     8 ms     8 ms  [Kind of my IP].ntlworld.ie [My_IP]
  3     7 ms     7 ms     9 ms  188-141-126-1.dynamic.upc.ie [188.141.126.1]
  4    53 ms     8 ms     9 ms  84.116.238.50
  5     9 ms     8 ms     8 ms  213.46.165.18
  6    11 ms   104 ms     8 ms  209.85.252.198
  7    13 ms    18 ms    10 ms  72.14.235.141
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9    10 ms     8 ms     9 ms  de-in-f100.1e100.net [74.125.24.100]
```

**ipconfig /all**

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : PC_NAME
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C4-85-08-43-86-37
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C4-85-08-43-86-3A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C4-85-08-43-86-36
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7cc9:627d:a372:d014%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.10(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 14 June 2014 13:27:28
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 24 June 2014 17:52:10
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 314869000
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-3E-44-A1-E8-03-9A-DD-05-36

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%12
                                       89.101.160.4
                                       89.101.160.5
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E8-03-9A-DD-05-36
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{09812F18-3847-40F7-8A73-8B3142155535}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{3C02EA27-66E8-483B-B613-9DDF25B777C2}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{25320524-8E25-4DAC-AF6F-B9E4C76F6BF8}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:202a:921:a69b:85e7(Prefe
rred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::202a:921:a69b:85e7%16(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{B8761C80-6080-4C2B-B307-2472A3B71C3C}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

First 2 octets:  89.100.

Comment: Let me understand - 1. you have a public static IP address? 2. when you say "my static IP only gets resolved..." - do you mean the noip FQDN you have doesn't resolve outside of your home network?  Can you do some tests from external networks?

Comment: Thanks for that what kind of tests would you like me to do? Couple of weeks ago I was able to use either static IP or ***.no-ip.com for accessing the service hosted on my home server. Now neither works. If I type external static IP at home it works, but not from outside.

Comment: Could it be that your external IP has changed? I know that the ISPs in my country, due to a shortage in IPv4 addresses, put everyone behind NAT.
What happens if you try access from your home using the noip address? does it still work?

Comment: The IP address is correct (what's my IP query returns it), I can use it for accessing the service only from home. I'd thought noip's DUK does not issue me a new IP but rather keeps itself aware of changes in my IP (as strictly speacking it's not static really) - nevertheless can I call them and ask about NAT - and if so does it stop me from using my public IP from outside of the network?

Comment: How did you checked your IP? if you're behind NAT services like whatsmyip.com will return the ISP's IP (and it'll be the same as noip).
You need to access your router and see what address has been allocated for you, and then compare it to noip.
As for noip, it doesn't change your IP - sorry if I somehow misled you.
You should ask your ISP, what's the worst the can happen?
And yes, if you're behind NAT (either ISPs or your own router), you need port forwarding (like you did on your own router).

Comment: I think first step would be to find out if the ip still matches. If you are at home just google "what is my ip" and click on the first result then you will see what ip you are using to access the internet.

Comment: @EliadTech Thanks for that - like I said I'm in position whereby things suddenly got broken - so I'm trying to find a tipping point to solve the problem. I was never much into networking, a few days back I though that if my external IP works from home it must have been worked from outside which proved to be wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ivan Viktorovic - That's exactly how I found it - and the address does work fine withing my home network but is not working from outside.

Comment: Are you able to ping the ip from outside or tracert? As well i would turn on detailed log on the router (if possible, most simple home use routers have only very limited options) and then check write down your ip when you try to use your website from the external ip. After a try look for that ip in the logs. If you cant find any hints in the logs you must allready get blocked by the ISP.

Comment: @Ivan Usually pings gets blocked by most routers, so that won't give us any direction...

Comment: @Ivan - Request timed out. is what I'm getting when trying to ping it from outside.

Comment: OK that should be most likely a firewall setting to block a ping like ElidanTech said.

Comment: @Ivan Viktorovic - how do I find out which one - mine or provider's one though?

Comment: You could try to use the tracert or pathping command to determine what you last point is wich you are able to reach. When you got the ip you can look it up on different services who is the owner and it will be most likely your provider. But the ping test was just a quick idea. Sometimes ping helps troubleshooting but sometimes it has no value at all because its possible to block the ping protocol on you router but allow web access.

Comment: Apparently the last IP in the list is is PRIVATE--IANA-RESERVED one, does that help at all?

Comment: If you told us the IP address, we could check it from the outside (or you could also do that from outside your home). Please post the entire tracert for both inside and outside (or we could add the later for you). Disable temporarily your firewall and that of the router and test again, re-enabling them immediately afterwards.

Comment: @harrymc I'm not in position to disclose my IP, but if could tell me how do I produce traces I'll do that no problem.

Comment: Just do it using tracert or pathping as you did, from both inside and outside, but add the entire info to the post. You can mask out your IP.

Comment: I'm total nocice - could you get me the command to run?

Comment: In the command prompt (cmd) run "command IP-address > file" for both commands and then include the two output files in the post. More info: [tracert](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162326) and [pathping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958876.aspx).

Comment: I've tested your IPand it looks totally blocked from my standpoint. Please post `ipconfig /all` here.

Comment: Also please post first 5 lines (except header) `tracert google.com` You can hide the last two octets for each IP (for example 12.36.xx.xx) but the first two are important to answer the question

Comment: The only connected adapter is the Wireless LAN adapter. Don't you have a wired adapter? Also I see that you have IPv6 on - try to turn it off in the PC and the router. I assume that your static IP is IPv4.

Comment: @harrymc how do I turn it off please? It's a server connected to a modem by air, the reason is the modem's too far from it:( If it's vital to get a wired connection I can probably work it out, but is it really the case?

Comment: For the PC, follow these [article1](http://www.informationweek.com/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-windows-7-/d/d-id/1099490?) and [article2](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-7/) and reboot. For the router I would need the exact model.

Comment: Does it require both PC and router to be changed? I have Thomson TWG870UIR. Also could I check is IPversion is definitely the root of the problem before making any changes?

Comment: The only check is to do it and see, easy enough to undo.

Comment: @harrymc I'll give it a go, will update you on the result.

Comment: Well, what are the results?

Comment: Run `$ dig <your domain>`. Is the IP address the same as the one returned when visiting [What's My IP](http://www.whatismyip.com/)? `dig` queries DNS records, and it should be the same as your WAN's IP.

Comment: are you sure that you are not confusing the internal LAN IP and the IP that your ISP provides ( always worth asking :-) )

Comment: @harrymc man please publish up yr answer I'm happy to give it to you. Didn't try it yet, moving to a different ISP due to unrelated reason.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your static IP is IPv4, but I see that you have IPv6 on,
which may cause a confusion.

Try to turn IPv4 off in the PC and the router.

As far as the PC is concerned, here are some useful resources.

[**How To Disable IPv6 On Windows 7**](http://www.informationweek.com/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-windows-7-/d/d-id/1099490?) (article 1)

In Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center, click the connection, then Properties,
uncheck "Internet protocol version 6" and OK.

[**How To Disable IPv6 In Windows 7**](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-7/) (article 2)

To make the above change permanent, use regedit to navigate to :
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TCPIP6\Parameters`.

Click `Parameters` in the left sidebar, then right-click on the right and choose:
`New > DWORD (32-bit)`. Name it `DisabledComponents` and set its value to 0.

Reboot to check if IPv6 is truly turned off.

Before doing registry work, ensure your backups are done and create a system restore point.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your internal ip address got renewed from the dhcp server on your router to a new ip causing any port forwarding you've done to point to the wrong ip address in your internal network and also causing the domain from noip to point to your static ip but not the correct ip on your internal network?

Sounds highly probable that that is the issue.